# What in the world does this iTunes Terms & Conditions about Virginia & California mean?

Tags: itunes-store

> Neither Issuer nor Apple is responsible for lost or stolen Gift Certificates, iTunes Cards, Content Codes, or Allowances. Risk of loss and title for Gift Certificates, iTunes Cards, and Allowances transmitted electronically pass to the purchaser in Virginia upon electronic transmission to the recipient. Risk of loss and title for Content Codes transmitted electronically pass in California upon electronic transmission from Apple; for avoidance of doubt, such recipient may not always be you.

Are they just fooling with us?  Does anybody know what the sentences about Virginia and California actually mean, and the "for avoidance of doubt"?

Answer (score 1):

"For avoidance of doubt" is legal speak for "let me summarize this in a way that handles any and all cases I might not have explicitly called out in any clause in the contract". It's a catch-all term used to say "this is it". It can cap damages or dues or liability. [Here's a good example and explanation](http://www.thepassivevoice.com/05/2011/how-to-read-a-book-contract-%E2%80%93-for-avoidance-of-doubt/):

> Contract clauses beginning with the phrase, “For the avoidance of
>   doubt” are a common feature of business contracts.
>
> For example, Company A is negotiating a three-year contract with
>   Company B to purchase twenty different products from Company B. The
>   contract includes ten pages outlining minimum purchases, pricing and
>   quantity discounts, price adjustments for changes in raw materials
>   costs, methods of calculating credits for returns, etc., with
>   variations for each product.
>
> Company A carefully analyzes all the different combinations of prices,
>   refunds, etc., but wants to make certain it doesn’t receive a big bill
>   as a result of unanticipated future permutations.
>
> Company A might insert a clause in the contract that says, “For the
>   avoidance of doubt, Company A will never be required to pay Company B
>   more than $2 million during any calendar month.” (PG has somewhat
>   simplified the likely language.)
>
> With this clause in place, as Company A’s CFO manages cash flow, she
>   knows she will never have to write a monthly check for more than $2
>   million to Company B.

In the case of the iTunes contract it says first that any of "Gift Certificates, iTunes Cards, and Allowances" are handled in the state of Virginia -- presumably they use this state for these transactions as it offers something ammenable to Apple when it comes to handling these things. You can see what Virginia has for state laws around gift cards [here](http://www.scripsmart.com/states/13-virginia-gift-card-law). They're rated "red" by that site meaning they're fairly anti-consumer, pro-seller there. From their summary chart:

> *Good*
>
> - Only cards with an expiration date escheat to the State of Virginia after 5 years
> - Virginia has legally defined the notion of a gift card
> - Virginia has legally specified whether or not gift cards escheat to the state
>
> *Bad*
>
> - No limits on expiration dates
> - No maximum post-sale fee or minimum time frame before charging monthly fees
> - Merchants are not required to give cash back
> - Virginia does not maintain a consumer-centric web page dedicated to gift card laws

Those bad things would look good to me if I was Apple.

As for "Content Codes" passing to you via California, again it likely goes back to some legal goodness the state of California affords a company sending out content codes that other states do not. So Apple says "we're doing this type of business, with you, via California and you agree to that".

Caveat lector: *I am not a lawyer; I just play one on the Stack Exchange network...*